# How do you tell what repository a package is from in package-list-packages?

Tags: emacs

```
package-archives
(("marmalade" . "http://marmalade-repo.org/packages/") ("gnu" . "http://elpa.gnu.org/packages/") ("melpa" . "http://melpa.milkbox.net/packages/"))
```

When I look at the `package-list-packages` list, how do I know which of these three sources a certain row is sourced from?

Comment: Good question. I don't know how to see it from that view. I do know that if you `package-list-packages`, and multiple repos contain the same package, it shows you the latest version, whichever repo that might be from. Same with `package-install` - it will get the latest version. I usually grep through `.emacs.d/elpa/archives/REPO/archive-contents` to see which repo a package is from, but I'd be interested to see if it's possible to do it this way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my trunk build, with multiple repositories enabled, the `package-list-packages` view contains an "Archive" column that is populated for available (uninstalled) packages, e.g.:

```
Package            Version      Status     Archive    Description
ace-window         0.5.0        available  melpa-s... Quickly switch windows using `ace-jump-mode'.
ack                1.3          available  gnu        Interface to ack-like source code search tools
```

Similarly, when I press `RET` on a package in this view, I get something like this:

```
ac-slime is an available package.

     Status: Available from melpa-stable -- Install
    Archive: melpa-stable
    Version: 0.7
   Requires: auto-complete-1.4, slime-2.9, cl-lib-0.5
    Summary: An auto-complete source using slime completions
   Homepage: https://github.com/purcell/ac-slime
```

Again, the "Archive" shows this package's source.

Unfortunately, installed packages do not seem to include information about which archive they came from.